# UISearchBar not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am having `UISearchBar` above `UITableView`.  Its not filtering the data

Here is my code

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text {

    if (text) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", text];
        _filteredDataArray = [_dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    }

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

`dataArray` is an `NSMutableArray` and `filteredDataArray` is an `NSArray`.  I've tried the solutions which are given already but its not working that's why am asked again... What I am doing wrong

Comment: Does `_filteredDataArray ` have any value? Did you handle the search active in your `cellForRow`?

Comment: have you set delagte for uiserchbar

Comment: Which array are you using for search tableView _dataArray or _filteredDataArray?

Comment: can you show the output of _dataArray

Comment: Yeah I'm silly about this issue. I forget to handle this in cellForRow thanks @Tj3n

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS CODE FOR SEARCH FILTER:**

```
  - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text {
        if (text) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", text];
            _filteredDataArray = [_dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        }
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess u need to see this, try this function it works for me, but its in swift 3.0, hope it helps you too.

```
func searchFromList(searchText:String, mainArray:AnyObject, key:String) -> AnyObject{
    var searchArray:[AnyObject]
    searchArray = []

    if searchText.length > 0 {
        if mainArray.count > 0 {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(key) contains[c] %@", searchText)
            searchArray = mainArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
        }
    }
    return searchArray
}
```